# dragging/dropping and triggers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a drag and drop functionality.  I have a game object that lies on a cube (like a table).  I want to allow the player to drag and drop this object to multiple "hot spots".  At the same time, while this is a 3D game, they should not be allowed to drag the object off of the table, above it, bellow it, etc.  Just drag across the top of the table.  The way I have this setup is like this:

1. On the table top (a cube with a rigid body)I have two planes. This plane is just decorative to let the user see where to drop to.  Each of these planes has a child plane (a much smaller area, centered in the parent).  This child has a Box Collider (isTrigger= true) that extends high up into the air, like a pole sticking out of the ground)
2. I then have a cube that has a rigid body and a box collider (isTrigger= true).  This cube is instantiated onto the "table" top, over one of the hot spots.

**HotSpotCode.cs**

```
public class HotSpotCodeScript : MonoBehaviour {      

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        DraggableObject ds = other.GetComponent<DraggableObject>();        
        ds.startPos = this.gameObject.transform.position;   

    }
}
```

**DraggableObject.cs**

```
public class DraggableObject : MonoBehaviour {       
    float lerpTime = 1f;
    float currentLerpTime;
    float moveDistance = 10f;
    Plane plane;    
    public Vector3 startPos, endPos;
    public bool drag;
    Vector3 position;

    void Start(){
        startPos = transform.position;
        endPos = transform.position + transform.up * moveDistance;
    }
    void OnMouseDown(){    
        plane = new Plane(Vector2.up, transform.position);
        drag = true; // start dragging
    }
    void OnMouseUp(){
        lerp();
        drag = false;
    }   
    private void lerp() {       
        currentLerpTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (currentLerpTime > lerpTime)
        {
            currentLerpTime = lerpTime;
        }

        float perc = currentLerpTime / lerpTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, perc);
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        position = transform.localPosition;
        if (drag)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            float distance;

            if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
            {                
                transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance);
            }
        }
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
       endPos = other.transform.position;
    }
}
```

This code mostly works somewhat.  I am able to drag the object around and it won't leave the plan it it resides on, for short distances.  But, the further away I drag the object, then release it, the more likely it is that the object will not snap back to its original start position and will get stuck somewhere along the way.  I am not sure if this is an issue with the Lerp() function or maybe how the plane it is dragged across is created. Can anyone help me out?  If you need more info, please let me know.  I've been working on this for weeks and haven't gotten much further that this.

Another issue that pops up, as well, is that when the object that is being dragged is released, and comes into contact with the hot spot's collider, it stops the object at its exact point.  So, if a corner of the cube comes into contact with the collider, the cube will not come to rest centered on the hot spot.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that, when I drag and release the draggable object, it doesn't always stay at the correct Y axis.  As mentioned above, this should only be draggable on the plane it resides on, not off of it.  I am not sure why this is happening but maybe this is the cause?

Comment: You have those files labeled as .js, but that syntax is definitely C#, intentional?

Comment: @code 11 typo, sorry.  I will fix that.